# Query by product category, product tags and price in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy, price

I am trying to make a simple form to query woocommerce products wine based on form input fields as follows:

- Selected category (Vine type, eg. red wine, white wine etc..) - Input type dropdown
- Select Winery Tag 1 dropdown
- Select Wine Sort Tag 2 dropdown
- Select wine region Tag 3 dropdown
- Price Range dropdown

Filtering by category and price works, however tags give mixed results and i cannot figure out why.

This is how my form looks like to give some context:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
$custom_query_args = array(
      'post_type'               => 'product',
      'post_status'             => 'publish',
      'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
      'order'               => 'DESC',
      'posts_per_page'      => 3,
      'product_tag'           => array($tag1, $tag2, tag3), 
      'tax_query'           => array(
             array(
               'taxonomy'       => 'product_cat',
               'terms'      => array( esc_attr( $category ) ),
               'field'      => 'slug',
               'operator'       => 'OR'                            
                      )),
                //Price
                'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'key' => '_price',
                        'value' => array($clow, $chigh),
                        'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                        'type' => 'NUMERIC'
                    )
              )
        );
```

From the input fields, I have 3 variables for product tags (like `$tag1`, `$tag2`, `$tag3`), 1 variable for product category (like `$category`) and 2 variables for the price range (like `$clow` and `$chigh`) which are the price from to.

Anyone have an idea why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some little mistakes in your code:

- There is a missing `$` in `tag3`,
- `OR` is not an `operator` value (and it's not needed),
- Each **Product tag** need to be in a **separated `tax_query` array** to get your filters working.

So try the following modified code instead:

```
$custom_query_args = array(
    'posts_per_page'      => 3,
    'post_type'           => 'product',
    'post_status'         => 'publish',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'order'               => 'DESC',
    'tax_query'           => array(
        // Product category filter
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'terms'    => array( esc_attr( $category ) ),
            'field'    => 'slug',
        ),
        // Product tag 1 filter
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
            'terms'    => array($tag1),
            'field'    => 'slug',
        ),
        // Product tag 2 filter
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
            'terms'    => array($tag2),
            'field'    => 'slug',
        ),
        // Product tag 3 filter
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
            'terms'    => array($tag3),
            'field'    => 'slug',
        ),
    ),
    // Price filter
    'meta_query'  => array( array(
        'key'     => '_price',
        'value'   => array($clow, $chigh),
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
        'type'    => 'NUMERIC'
    ) ),
);
```

Tested and works.

Comment: @user3808588 On the `tax_query` each term value type is defined with the **`field`** argument that can be `term_id`, or `slug` or `name`… In this query all are defined as `slug`, and you can change them as you need.

Answer (score 0):

I have found easier way to do this and its better because when no filters are present it will display all products and the query is also smaller, like this:

```
    $category = 'category-slug-here'; //String, but can accept array?
    $tags = 'comma,delimeted,tags,here'; //I build string with tags needed no array.
    $clow = 0; //min price int
    $chigh = 200; //max price int

                $custom_query_args = array(
                    'posts_per_page' => '12',
                    'product_cat' => $category,
                    'post_type' => 'product',
                    'product_tag' => $tags,
                    // Price filter
                    'meta_query'  => array( array(
                        'key'     => '_price',
                        'value'   => array($clow, $chigh),
                        'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                        'type'    => 'NUMERIC'
                    ) ),
                );
```

Are there any bad sides doing it like this, since i have tested it using different filter tags and it works like i planned it to?